# How to specify explicit axis values with Altair labelExpr. Expression Parse Error

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I am trying to implement the [hexbin plot](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/hexbins.html) example. However, I am running into issues with my data being fractional. In the example, they use

```
.transform_calculate(
    # This field is required for the hexagonal X-Offset
    xFeaturePos='(day(datum.' + yField + ') % 2) / 2 + month(datum.' + xField + ')'
)
```

to create the staggered offset. I found with fractional x and y values this causes the hexagons to be adjusted increasingly to the right.

[image]

I solved this problem by creating two index columns that are integers that represent my x and y values.

[image: Hexagonal bin plot with integer axis]

I found the `values` parameter in the alt.Axis() object with I have tried using to overwrite the axis labels.

[image]

Unfortunately, scaling is incorrect. I know a regular rectangular heat map wouldn't have this issue. But because each hexagon is from a mean of binned data, I like to think that the hexagon helps remind the audience the data is binned. (was also planning to add that tidbit of info in the x-axis or on the title)

Also, in all cases the x-axis resolution is not high enough, though that I think would be a simpler problem.

---

*update*
I've found I can use the `labelExpr` parameter in `alt.Axis` to append strings to the value.

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot seem too completely rewrite them. I've take approaches from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68841230/how-to-replace-the-axis-label-in-altair).
I am trying to use [vega expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) to modify just the first label.

`labelExpr="datum.label == 1.5 ? '0.5'"`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Missing the default value after the vega expression for `else`, `:`